# When I upload my excel file to R, the column titles are in the rows and the data seems all jumbled. How do I fix this?

Tags: r, excel, csv

*hi literally day one new coder*

On the excel sheet, my data looks organized, but when I upload my file to R, it's not able to read the excel properly and the column headers are in the rows and the data seems randomized.

So far I have tried:

```
library(readxl)
dataset <-read_excel("pathname")
View(dataset)
```

Also tried:

```
dataset <-read_excel("pathname", sheet=1, colNames=TRUE)
```

Also tried to use the package `openxlsx`
but nothing is giving me the correct, organized data set.

I tried formatting my Excel to a CSV file, and the CSV file looks exactly like the data that shows up on R (both are messed up).

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Hi @Ani, welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)! For your CSV file, have you tried `dataset <- read.csv("pathname", header = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 1):

I deal with importing .xlsx into R frequently.  It can be challenging due to the flexibility of the excel platform. I generally use `readxl::read_xlsx()` to fetch data from .xlsx files. My suggestions:

First, specify exactly the data you want to import with the `range` argument.

> A cell range to read from, as described in cell-specification. Includes typical Excel
> ranges like "B3:D87", possibly including the sheet name like "Budget!B2:G14"

Second, if there are there merged cells or other formatting challenges in column headers, I resort to setting `col_names = FALSE`. And supplying clean names after import with `names(df) <- c("first_col", "second_col")`

Third, if there are merged cells elsewhere in the spreadsheet I generally I resort to "fixing" them in excel (not ideal but easier for my use case), however, others may have suggestions on a programmatic fix.

It may be helpful to provide a screenshot of your spreadsheet.